# How do I filter tags with class in Python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape images from a site using beautifulsoup HTML parser.

There are 2 kinds of image tags for each image on the site. One is for the thumbnail and the other is the bigger size image that only appears after I click on the thumbnail and expand. The bigger size  tag contains a class="expanded-image" attribute.

I'm trying to parse through the HTML and get the "src" attribute of the expanded image which contains the source for the image.

When I try to execute my code, nothing happens. It just says the process finished without scraping any image. But when I don't try to filter the code and just give  tag as an argument, it downloads all the thumbnails.

Here's my code:

```
import webbrowser, requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata('https://boards.4chan.org/a/thread/30814')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

list = []

for i in soup.find_all("img",{"class":"expanded-thumb"}):
    list.append(i['src'].replace("//","https://"))

def download(url, pathname):
    if not os.path.isdir(pathname):
        os.makedirs(pathname)

    filename = os.path.join(pathname, url.split("/")[-1])
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)

for a in list:
    download(a,"file")
```

Comment: After expanding, I see the class of the expanded image as "expanded-thumb". Before expanding, however, the anchor (<a>) tag that wraps the img tag of the thumbnail contains the source URL for the full image. The anchor has class "fileThumb" and href "FULL_URL.png". I would start by collecting the wrapping anchors' href attribute. EDIT: in other words, parse it as if you haven't clicked on any of the thumbnails to expand them.

Comment: @luthervespers Thanks a lot, man. It worked quite well. Finally, after sinking hours I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a problem using "list" as a variable name. It's a type in python. Start with this (replacing TEST_4CHAN_URL with whatever thread you want), incorporating my suggestion from the comment above.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

TEST_4CHAN_URL = "https://boards.4chan.org/a/thread/<INSERT_THREAD_ID_HERE>"

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

htmldata = getdata(TEST_4CHAN_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, "html.parser")

src_list = []

for i in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"fileThumb"}):
    src_list.append(i['href'].replace("//", "https://"))

print(src_list)
```

Comment: The program already worked with your comment above, so thanks again, man. Question: Is this solution specific to this one site? If I want expanded images rather than thumbnails from any other site, do they also have an href like this that I can use without expanding image?

Comment: This solution is specific to one site (specific class name, etc.) You should study how any site/page behaves before and after the images are expanded. If the expanded version's full image link is in a tag's attributes, figure out which one.